# Does tagging a group on your timeline put that post on the group page?

Tags: facebook-groups

I would like to tag a group in a post on my personal timeline so that all group members see that post and any likes or comments subsequently attached to it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, tagging any group in your personal post will not put it on Group Timeline. It will on your Timeline. All associated Likes and Comments also will be only on your post.